# Readout File Path From HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, iframe

What I want to achieve is to read out the project name and version from the path of the file in my iframe. My iframe (when loaded) looks like this:

```
<iframe style="width: 100%; height: 40rem;" name="docu" src="/content/subpages/PROJECT_V1/index.html"</iframe>
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
"PROJECT V1"
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Depends. This is murky waters. If it is 3rd party page, then there is a chance that no. They can deny iframes and read them with javascript. You can do it with PHP on the server-side, there are several ways, but the easiest is using `file_get_contents()`, and then you can process it. If it is your own page, you could just pass it to URL via variable, and then you can process it with javascript easily.

Comment: just guessing maybe you want something like that: `console.log((/\/([^/]+_[^/]+)\//.exec(document.querySelector('iframe[name="docu"]').getAttribute('src')))[0].replace('_', ' '));`

Comment: It would be good if you could clarify the precise circumstances in which you're trying to do this.